# Drawing a PDA for a language

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I am initiating myself into TOC and using sort of random resources from the web.
I was looking at this problem from a Berkeley problem set:
Construct a PDA to accept 
$$
L = {a^ib^j|i \neq j , 2i \neq j}
$$
And I don't understand the given solution here.(Problem 4)
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~isabelle/cs302/ps3-solutions.pdf

When can we say this machine accepts a string?
From my understanding, it seems to accept ab,aabb,aaabbb etc as well when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different definitions of push-down automata that differ in the details of the acceptance condition. One common condition that is (presumably) in use here is that a word is accepted if:

1. The push-down automaton arrives in an accepting state,
2. The stack is empty.

If you follow the behaviour of the automaton in the answer, you will find that for words $a^ib^i$ or $a^ib^{2i}$, if you arrive in a final state, the stack will not be empty, so the word is not accepted.